# Unexpected token > (es6 arrow function) in Meteor Modules.js

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the Meteor package 'modules.js' and I'm getting the error 'Unexpected token >' which is referring to the arrow function below. I'm really confused by this because the rest of my code uses es6. Any thoughts?

**In modules.js**

> W20160812-14:17:54.153(2)? (STDERR
>   W20160812-14:17:54.154(2)? (STDERR) packages\modules.js:238
>   W20160812-14:17:54.154(2)? (STDERR) res.on('data', (chunk) => buffer += chunk.toString('utf8')); 
>   W20160812-14:17:54.155(2)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
>   W20160812-14:17:54.155(2)? (STDERR)     at 
> C:\Users\User\Websites\App.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:278:30
>   W20160812-14:17:54.155(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
>   W20160812-14:17:54.156(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach 
> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
>   W20160812-14:17:54.156(2)? (STDERR)     at 
> C:\Users\User\Websites\App.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:133:5

Comment: Can you try this : res.on('data', chunk => buffer += chunk.toString('utf8'));

Comment: What Meteor version are you using? Does it use `standard-minifier-js`?

Comment: @MasterAM 1.3 and yes.

Comment: @Pankaj Jatav It's a read only file and if I try to make any changes to it it just reverts back to what it was after I run the app.

Comment: Can you show the full error message, as well as the specific package that your are using?

Comment: The full error message is above. The specific package is Meteor's 'modules' package--version 0.5.1. I basically followed all the instructions on this page https://docs.meteor.com/packages/modules.html. More specifically, I need this so I can use this NPM module https://github.com/totaljs/node-paypal-express-checkout.

Comment: I can see the error "SyntaxError" which clearly says that you have some syntax error.

Comment: I'm also using the pbastowski:angular-babel package. I think that might be part of the problem.

Comment: Do you have the `ecmascript` package installed? `meteor add ecmascript`

Comment: I can't use it because it conflicts with the pbastowski:angular-babel package. I need this package because it's an Angular-Meteor app.

Comment: I should be able to use this package instead of Meteor's 'modules' package (https://github.com/pbastowski/angular-meteor-babel). Yet it gives me this error (without the modules package): TypeError: Property 'require' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: `res.on('data', (chunk) => { buffer += chunk.toString('utf8'); }); ` should work.